# Neo4j Java API enable the equivalent of apoc.import.file.enabled=true

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j Java API to create a database from an external file by the APOC procedure XML import.
Everything works fine, except when I create a database from a **local** file.
I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Import from files not enabled, please set apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your *neo4j.conf*
```

I just need to enable the import from file as described, but since I have no neo4j.conf file because I'm using the API, I set my db properties as follows:

```
neo4jDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( dbpath )
            .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "512M" )
            .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.string_block_size, "60" )
            .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.array_block_size, "300" )
            .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.allow_file_urls, "true")
            .newGraphDatabase();
```

The problem is that I cannot find the counterpart here for the import of local files, I can just use the web url for now.

Is there a way to enable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this : `.setConfig("apoc.import.file.enabled", "true")`

**Update**

Like you found, this is deprecated. To avoid that, you have to build a `Setting` and use the `setConfig( Setting<?> setting, String value )` :

```
import static org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting;
import static org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.BOOLEAN;
import static org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.FALSE;
...
new GraphDatabaseFactory()
      .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( dbpath )
      .setConfig(
        setting( "apoc.import.file.enabled", BOOLEAN, FALSE ),
        True
      )
...
```

Comment: Excellent! Very simple solution!

Comment: Anyway, it is marked as "deprecated" and Eclipse write a line over this source code line. If I suppress the warning, during the export this line is not considered. Is there a workaround?