# Embedded Neo4j APOC procedure apoc.load.json not working

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I went through a couple of similar threads but none save my problem. I am running an embedded Neo4j instance (version 3.5, enterprise edition). When configuring DB I override plugin dir to location where I have my APOC jar (also 3.5 version).

Here is neo4j.conf file:

```
dbms.logs.debug.level=DEBUG
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

I can confirm that configuration is correctly read upon database setup since on listing of configs (using `dbms.listConfig()`) I can confirm custom settings are present.

Issue occur upon running APOC procedure apoc.load.json:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Import from files not enabled, please set apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf
```

Also other APOC procedure (fore example `apoc.util.validate` works without issues).

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542808/neo4j-java-api-enable-the-equivalent-of-apoc-import-file-enabled-true